# JPA + @OneToMany + DELETE: Item is not deleted if I access parent later

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I got a `Deal` which can have multiple `DealItems`.

The `DealItems` are linked in the `Deal` with the following JPA annotation:

```
public class DealEntity extends BasicEntity {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<DealItemEntity> items;
...
```

This is the relation inside a `DealItem`:

```
public class DealItemEntity extends BasicEntity {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "deal_id", nullable = false)
private DealEntity deal;
...
```

When I delete a `DealItem` it is deleted and persited again, when when I access the `Deal` after the deletion, see here:

```
public FullDealResponse deleteDealItem(final String dealCode, final long dealItemId) {

    DealEntity dealEntity = dealControl.findDealByDealCode(dealCode);

    if (dealEntity == null) {
        throw new WorkbenchGenericErrorException("Deal not found");
    }

    DealItemEntity dealItemEntity = dealItemControl.findDealItemByIdAndDealId(dealItemId, dealEntity.getId());
    if (dealItemEntity == null) {
        throw new WorkbenchGenericErrorException("Deal item not found");
    }
    // this makes a database DELETE call that is executed after the session is done
    dealItemControl.deleteDealItem(dealItemEntity);
    
    // When I remove this and I do not return anything, the deletion works
    return this.getFullDealResponse(dealEntity);
}
```

EDIT:

This is `getFullDealResponse()` and `getFullDealItemResponse()`:

```
private FullDealResponse getFullDealResponse(final DealEntity dealEntity) {
    FullDealResponse response = new FullDealResponse();
    response.setDescription(dealEntity.getDescription());
    response.setTitle(dealEntity.getTitle());
    response.setDealCode(dealEntity.getDealCode());
    response.setCreatedAt(dealEntity.getCreatedAt());
    response.setUpdatedAt(dealEntity.getUpdatedAt());

    // get related items
    List<FullDealItemResponse> itemsResponse = new ArrayList<FullDealItemResponse>();
    for (DealItemEntity dealItemEntity : dealEntity.getItems()) {
        itemsResponse.add(this.getFullDealItemResponse(dealItemEntity));
    }
    response.setItems(itemsResponse);
    return response;
}


private FullDealItemResponse getFullDealItemResponse(final DealItemEntity dealItemEntity) {
    FullDealItemResponse response = new FullDealItemResponse();
    response.setId(dealItemEntity.getId());
    response.setDescription(dealItemEntity.getDescription());
    response.setTitle(dealItemEntity.getTitle());
    response.setCreatedAt(dealItemEntity.getCreatedAt());
    response.setUpdatedAt(dealItemEntity.getUpdatedAt());

    return response;
}
```

This is `deleteDealItem()` and `delete()` function:

```
public void deleteDealItem(final DealItemEntity dealItemEntity) {
        super.delete(DealItemEntity.class, dealItemEntity.getId());
    }
protected void delete(final Class<?> type, final Object id) {
    Object ref = this.em.getReference(type, id);
    this.em.remove(ref);
}
```

Can this be solved when I switch the `CascadeType`, and if so, which would be the correct type? Or would I have to iterate over `Deal.getItems()`, remove the unwanted item, set the new list with `Deal.setItems()` and update only the `Deal` so it propagates the deletion?

What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I added the 2 response functions

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai thanks, I added the delete functions

Comment: Why do you complicate deleting with those wrapper methods and entity references? Why not just use `em.remove(dealItemEntity)` where ever you need it?

Comment: @pirho it is a huge project and I did not do the base setup, changing this would mean a lot of refactoring (the ECB pattern is used in the project). Also, I do not think that removing the wrappers would solve the problem as the problem is the bi-directional association mentioned by KavithakaranKanapathippillai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have replicated this code locally and verified my explanation

**Summary:**

1. Cascade does not have impact. Even if you remove your cascade operation, save each item separately , then when you come to this method, it will not delete your item.
2. To have same behaviour regardless of `deal.getItems` initialisation, You will have to delete the `dealItem` by removing it from `deal.getItems` in addition to deleting the dealItem directly.
3. On a bi-directional relationship, you will have to explicitly manage both sides. Exactly the same way, you add the dealItem to deal as well  set deal field of dealItem before you save.

**Overall Explanation**

- JPA can have only one representation of a particular item associated with it's session.
- It is the foundation for providing **Repeatble Read, Dirty Checking** etc.
- JPA also tracks every object associated with its session and If any of the tracked objects have changes, they will flushed when the transaction committed.
- When only `deal` object (with lazy `deaItems` collection) and the directly fetched `dealItem` are the only two entities associated with the session, then JPA has one presentation for each in the session, since there is no conflict, when you delete it, it deletes it via `dealItemControl.deleteDealItem` the dealItem is **deleted**
- However, once you call `deal.getItems`, JPA not only manages deal, but also **every** dealItem associated  with the `deal` object. So when when you delete the `dealItemControl.deleteDealItem`, JPA has an issue because deal.getItems tells it is not marked for delete. So the delete is not issued.

**Reference: JPA QL generated also confirms my explanation**

**1. With `deal.getItems` and Queries Generated**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<DealItemEntity> items;
```

```
DealEntity dealEntity = dealControl.findDealByDealCode(dealCode);
....
dealItemControl.deleteDealItem(dealItemEntity);
....
dealEntity.getItems()
```

```
select deal0_.* from deal deal0_  where deal0_.id=?

select  dealitem0_.* 
        deal1_.*
    from
        deal_item dealitem0_ inner join deal deal1_  on dealitem0_.deal_id=deal1_.id 
    where
        dealitem0_.id=?

select items0_.* from deal_item items0_  where items0_.deal_id=?
```

**2. Without `deal.getItems` and Queries Generated**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<DealItemEntity> items;
```

```
DealEntity dealEntity = dealControl.findDealByDealCode(dealCode);
....
dealItemControl.deleteDealItem(dealItemEntity);
```

```
select deal0_.* from deal deal0_  where deal0_.id=?


select  dealitem0_.* 
        deal1_.*
    from
        deal_item dealitem0_ inner join deal deal1_  on dealitem0_.deal_id=deal1_.id 
    where
        dealitem0_.id=?

delete from deal_item  where id=?
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and the detailed answer!